# Altering existing table vs creating new table which approach is beast

Tags: sql, sql-server

One scenario came to us today. Here we have a database table where more than 1 million records already present and now we want to alter table which will add one column. That column will be having default value 0. By altering the table with column which will be remain 0 for all existing records will it affect performance.

Also,here that column value remains 0 for 99.9% only if some action triggered by user then it will change to 1.So shall I create new table to hold those value or alter existing table.

I would like to know advantages or disadvantages of both approaches

Comment: Tables don't have "records"; they have columns and rows. As for your question, creating a new table, copying all the data, re-indexing it, moving all the constraints, and dropping the old one is going to easily be far more expensive that adding a new column to an existing table (which can be minimally logged (if I recall correctly), if you're using a `DEFAULT` value that you're populating at the same time using `WITH VALUES`).

Comment: I don't want to copy data from one table to other. Just to create a bridge table to hold the value of newly added column which will have a structure like [PK,FK(exsisting table PK),NewColumn]. or alter existing table that will be like [PK,ABC,BCA,...,NewColumn] exsiting table has 1 million records.

Comment: What is a "bridge table"? There only appears to be one table involved here, and a bridge would imply you are creating a new table to "bridge" 2 tables. Do you mean you want to create a new table that just has a the PK of the original table as an FK, and then a new column for your new column? You *could* do that, but if it's a one-to-one relationship it feels like the column should be in the original table. Especially if the table is simply a FK and a `bit` column.

Comment: "Better" is both subjective and relative - so your question is offtopic for those reasons. But if you want to know, then try both and evaluate the "performance" based on whatever criteria you desire. That is the ONLY way to know and the ONLY way to answer questions related to performance. Note - why do you think a bridge table needs yet another primary key that is different from the primary key of the parent table. Nothing you wrote suggested this was needed. Do not blindly add an identify column PK to every table.

Comment: And have you considered most the code that references this table will need to be updated? If you alter the table, you will discover why `select *` is such a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.  If you use `0`, then the existing data will need to be rewritten to make space for the new column.  (There might be an exception if you already have bit columns and the new column is a bit.)

Rewriting the table is a one-time operation and it does take time, although on one million rows, it shouldn't take too long.

The alternative is to create a second table to store flags that are set.  This could be as either columns or one row per flag.  You would use `left join` to load data from this table.

I would be biased to having a second table, but not for performance reasons.  Rather, I would like to include other information about the flag being set -- notably the date/time of when the flag is set.  Also, I might want to distinguish between values that default to `0` versus those that are explicitly reset to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

> By altering the table with column which will be remain 0 for all
> existing records will it affect performance.

The answer depends on nullability of your new column and on your server version:

[image: Randal's explanation]

[Misconceptions around adding columns to a table by P.Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-adding-columns-to-a-table/)

So if your server `@@version` is >= 2012 and your column is nullable, even if you fill it in with the default value by using `WITH VALUES` clause will not affect the performance as it will be metadata only operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you care mostly about "what is best for the ongoing operation of my system", rather than which option is easiest for the one-off change.

To make sure I understand your question, I'd like to restate it with a (made up) example. Please comment if I've misunderstood.

You have a table with > 1 million rows; let's pretend it's called `people`. The table has several foreign key relationships (e.g. `countries`, a person lives in a country, and is in turn related to many other table via foreign keys (e.g. `interactions`, a person interacts with the system).

You have now identified an additional attribute of `people`. The attribute is mandatory (so you are setting a default value), and of type integer.

You say it's "only incremented when the user interacts with the system"; it would be great if you could be more explicit about that.

In (very) general terms, adding an integer column with a default value to your table will have no noticable effect on performance of your existing queries. Performance impact happens primarily when you include columns in `where` clauses and/or `joins`. So, `select * from people where name = ? and age > ?`  will behave exaxctly as it does today.

When you add that column to a where clause, you may get a slightly better performance if the column is included in an index, because it may filter out more rows. `select * from people where name = ? and age > ? and new_column = ?`  might reduce the number of rows to inspect, and thus improve speed.

If I've understood your question, you're considering creating a new table to hold that data instead, presumably with a foreign key relationship (`person_id`), and a value for that new attribute.

So, if it's true that the attribute is mandatory, and has a default value of 0, in the business domain sense, then creating a separate table makes no real sense. You want to keep all mandatory attributes for an entity in the same table.

If the attribute is not mandatory, it gets a little murkier - you can make a case for attributes that belong together, e.g. "address" to have their own tables. However, for a single attribute, it would be counter intuitive.